# Remove exporting button from HighChart Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, highcharts

Is there anyway to remove the exporting button from the line chart in iOS ?

Below is my code :

```
HIChartView *chartView = [[HIChartView alloc] initWithFrame:self.lineGraphView2.bounds];
    chartView.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

HIColor *color = [[HIColor alloc] initWithHexValue:@"283445"];

HIColor *greeColorHex = [[HIColor alloc] initWithHexValue:@"00B84A"];
HIColor *redColorHex = [[HIColor alloc] initWithHexValue:@"A3001F"];
//    color = [color initWithHexValue:@"000000"];

HIChart *chart = [[HIChart alloc] init];
chart.plotBackgroundColor = color;
chart.backgroundColor = color;

HICredits *credits = [[HICredits alloc] init];
credits.enabled = @0;

HIExporting *exporting = [[HIExporting alloc] init];
exporting.enabled = @0;

HIOptions *options = [[HIOptions alloc]init];
options.exporting.enabled = false;

HITitle *title = [[HITitle alloc]init];
title.text = @"";

HISubtitle *subtitle = [[HISubtitle alloc]init];
//    subtitle.text = @"Source: thesolarfoundation.com";

HIYAxis *yaxis = [[HIYAxis alloc]init];
yaxis.title = [[HITitle alloc]init];
yaxis.title.text = @"";
yaxis.gridLineColor = color;
yaxis.gridLineWidth = @0;


HILegend *legend = [[HILegend alloc]init];
legend.layout = @"vertical";
legend.align = @"right";
legend.verticalAlign = @"middle";

HIPlotOptions *plotoptions = [[HIPlotOptions alloc] init];
plotoptions.series = [[HISeries alloc] init];
plotoptions.series.label = [[HILabel alloc] init];
plotoptions.series.label.connectorAllowed = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:false];
plotoptions.series.lineWidth = @2;

HILine *line1 = [[HILine alloc]init];
line1.name = @"Shares Price";
line1.data = graphPointsMutableArray;
line1.color = greeColorHex;
line1.threshold = @10;

HIResponsive *responsive = [[HIResponsive alloc] init];

HIRules *rules1 = [[HIRules alloc] init];
rules1.condition = [[HICondition alloc] init];
rules1.chartOptions = @{
                        @"legend" : @{
                                @"layout": @"horizontal",
                                @"align": @"center",
                                @"verticalAlign": @"bottom"
                                }

                        };
responsive.rules = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:rules1, nil];

options.title = title;
options.subtitle = subtitle;
options.yAxis = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:yaxis];
options.legend = legend;
options.plotOptions = plotoptions;
options.series = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:line1, nil];
options.responsive = responsive;
options.chart = chart;
options.credits = credits;
options.exporting = exporting;
options.exporting.enabled = @0;
options.labels.enabled = @0;

chartView.options = options;

[self.lineGraphView2 addSubview:chartView];
```

I have read in the documentation to set `exporting.enable = false` but it's not working.

Comment: can you give us link of library so we can check it.

Comment: @NiravKotecha https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios

Comment: top right side "i" information button you have to hide right ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha http://prnt.sc/mgs5vp the button with 3 bars at top right.

Answer (score 1):

in `viewForHeaderInSection` method set exporting = NO

it will hide 3 bars button. **see below screenshot for more details :**

[image]

Comment: may i ask where are you doing this? i am not using any tableview or anything, a bit confused here.

Comment: this `DataTableViewController.m` file provided in HighFit library Folder --> Views

Comment: you can go through pod folder inside and find HighFit Folder --> view section and `DataTableViewController.m` file.

Comment: I got the hint from your answer i need to set enabled to @NO, exporting.enabled = @NO;

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I found in Swift.  Basically, you have to create a HINavigation object, and a HIButtonOptions object.  After setting the button options enabled property to false, you set the navigation's button options property to the button options object, and then set your HIOptions object's navigation object to the navigation object you created.  My obj-c isn't good enough to try typing it out in obj-c, so below is the Swift version of  my solution:

```
// init your options object
let options = HIOptions()

// hide hamburger button
let navigation = HINavigation() // init navigation object
let buttonOptions = HIButtonOptions() // init button options object
buttonOptions.enabled = false
navigation.buttonOptions = buttonOptions
options.navigation = navigation
```

Answer (score 0):

you set the exporting to false a couple of times, change that so it is set only one time like that in swift:

```
options.exporting = HIExporting()
options.exporting.enabled = NSNumber.init(booleanLiteral: false)
```